# invalid conversion from `int' to `int*' in array

Tags: c++, arrays

How can i set dimension of array from main program ?

I have Class Loza and I want create object(set capacity and price), and create field contains of "capacity" integers. But when i want set another number into field 
  like:  `aray[i] = 1;`  compiler will say:

```
invalid conversion from `int' to `int*' in array
```

How can i fix this problem ? I just want set element on index in field to another number(0/1)

```
class Loza {
public:

    Loza(int capacity, int price) {
        this->capacity = capacity;
        this->price = price;
        *aray = new int[capacity];
        for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
            aray[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    virtual ~Loza();

    void info();

    bool set(int i) {
        if (aray[i] == 0) {
            aray[i] = 1;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    int getCapacity() const {
        return capacity;
    }

    int getPrice() const {
        return price;
    }

    void setCapacity(int pocetMiest) {
        this->capacity = pocetMiest;
    }

    void setPrice(int cenaMiesta) {
        this->price = cenaMiesta;
    }

private:
    int capacity;
    int price;
    int *aray[];
};
```

Comment: No need to use a C array, and no need to use pointers and `new`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following up on Carl's answer, resizing the array is a nontrivial task.  If you want to set the capacity of the array, you'll need to generate new space on the heap (using 'new'), copy the old array into it, and delete the old array.  You should use `vector<int>` instead, which handles this movement of the space around the heap for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your array is declared as an array of `int *`, not an array of `int`.  You're also creating it incorrectly.  What you really want is:

```
int *aray;
```

and:

```
aray = new int[capacity];
```

In addition to that, your `setCapacity` method doesn't appear to attempt to actually change the capacity of the array you're creating.  That's going to bite you sooner or later.

The real C++ guys will say "don't use an array", though. There are C++ containers that do what you want already.